# Keyword suggestion or Auto Correction

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

When searching a keyword like `[botframework]` on search box, if the spelling of the keyword is not correct like `[botframewrok]` (which `o` and `r` are misplaced in `wrok`) the search result would be empty:

[image]

Now, my suggestion is, if the specified tag is not in the tag space, try to map the tag into the near tag and show the result of the auto-corrected tag. It might be this mapping be using the minimum Levenshtein distance.